# Как нормализировать работу скриптов в WebBrowser?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, webbrowser

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно заставить webbrowser нормально выполнять скрипты с динамических сайтов? При попытке посещения подобных сайтов начинает вылетать предупреждении "script error".

Answer (score 0):

У меня обычно получалось, что в нем старая версия IE, которая работает хуже, чем "родной" IE. Лечится вроде в реестре.

А лучше выкинуть его и вкатить Awesomium.

IE не может работать нормально.

Comment: Awesomium хорош, но для работы мне нужно получать массив HTMLElement с сайта и с ним работать, в webbrowser  мне хватало WebBrowser.Document . Буду признателен если скажите, как из awesomium подобное вытащить.

Comment: @ЮлийВедькал Голова работает? JS.